# How to find production methods only used by tests in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

Does anyone know if it's possible to identify production methods that are only referenced by unit test class methods?
I can see if a method has production or test uses by using the Find Usages option but I want to scan my whole codebase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not yet implemented, but there is an issue for it, please follow:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212420